# How can I get the value of this promise?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, jasmine, es6-promise

While I was writing unit tests I came across a use case where I have to use promises asynchronously.

How can I get the value of this promise?

```
let purposes: Promise<ProcessingPurpose[]> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return [{ id: 'id1', name:'p1'}, {id: 'id2', name: 'p2'}];
});
```

I tried this solution below. but I want to put the condition expect(value).toEqual(metadataServiceTest.getPurposes()) outside the THEN()

```
metadataV1ClientTestSpy.getAllProcessingPurposes.and.returnValue(purposes);
purposes.then(value => expect(value).toEqual(metadataServiceTest.getPurposes()));
```

The expected result should be an Array of Objects.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is to handle asynchronous operations.
Consequently, your code is not necessarily executed in the written order.

This is most commonly used for network related data fetching, but can also be used to parallelize the execution of Javascript code. As JS is otherwise mono-threaded.

If you put your condition outside the `then()`, you have no way to know whether or not `value` has been filed when `expect(value).toEqual(metadataServiceTest.getPurposes())` is executed.

Also, if your code is not asynchronous you may not need the Promise, which will give you back the linear flow you are expecting.